# Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am using the **spring batch boot example**. In my project, I have two batch jobs developed so far and in future will be having around 10 batch jobs running simultaneously.

I developed the code for the second batch job and when I started to run the 2nd batch job, I started getting the below error.

I have following doubts in my mind -

1. How can I run only 2nd batch for my development and unit testing ?
2. How can I run all the batch jobs in one go ?

Error which is coming -

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.batch.core.Job' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: exportemployeesJob,exportOrdersJob
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveNotUnique(DependencyDescriptor.java:215) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1350) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:580) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at com.prateek.SpringBatchClassicDbApplication.main(SpringBatchClassicDbApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]

2018-07-08 21:45:23.396 ERROR 11600 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field job in com.prateek.scheduler.EmployeesRunScheduler required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - exportemployeesJob: defined by method 'exportemployeesJob' in class path resource [com/prateek/job/EmployeesJob.class]
    - exportOrdersJob: defined by method 'exportOrdersJob' in class path resource [com/prateek/job/OrdersJob.class]


Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed
```

**OrdersJob.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class OrdersJob {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean(destroyMethod="")
    public JdbcCursorItemReader<Orders> ordersReader(){
        JdbcCursorItemReader<Orders> itemReader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
        itemReader.setDataSource(dataSource);
        itemReader.setSql("SELECT orderNumber, productName, msrp, priceEach "
                + "FROM products p "
                + "INNER JOIN orderdetails o "
                + "ON p.productcode = o.productcode "
                + "AND p.msrp > o.priceEach ");
                //+ "WHERE p.productcode = ? ");
        itemReader.setRowMapper(new OrdersRowMapper());
        itemReader.setIgnoreWarnings(true);

        return itemReader;
    }


    @Bean(destroyMethod="")
    public FlatFileItemWriter<Orders> ordersWriter(){
        FlatFileItemWriter<Orders> fileItemWriter = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();
        fileItemWriter.setResource(new FileSystemResource("csv/Orders.csv"));
        //fileItemWriter.setHeaderCallback(headerCallback());

        DelimitedLineAggregator<Orders> lineAggregator = new DelimitedLineAggregator<>();
        lineAggregator.setDelimiter(",");
        lineAggregator.setFieldExtractor(new PassThroughFieldExtractor<Orders>());

        fileItemWriter.setLineAggregator(lineAggregator);
        fileItemWriter.setShouldDeleteIfEmpty(true);

        return fileItemWriter;
    }


    // Step Execution
    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<Orders, Orders>chunk(10)
                .reader(ordersReader())
                .writer(ordersWriter())
                .build();
    }

    // Job Execution
    @Bean
    public Job exportOrdersJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory
                .get("exportOrdersJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .flow(step1())
                .end()
                .build();
    }
}
```

**EmployeesJob.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class EmployeesJob {
    public static final String DATE_FORMAT = "dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm-ssss";
    public static final DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean 
    public EmployeesProcessor employeesProcessor() {
        return new EmployeesProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public EmployeesRunScheduler scheduler() {
        return new EmployeesRunScheduler();
    }

    // This file helps to create CSV column aliases
    @Bean
    public EmployeesFlatFileWriterCallback headerCallback() {
        return new EmployeesFlatFileWriterCallback();
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod="")
    public JdbcCursorItemReader<Employees> employeesReader(){
        JdbcCursorItemReader<Employees> itemReader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
        itemReader.setDataSource(dataSource);
        itemReader.setSql("SELECT employeeNumber, lastName, firstName, extension, email, officeCode, reportsTo, jobTitle FROM employees ");
        itemReader.setRowMapper(new EmployeeRowMapper());
        // The fetch size can be controlled from the application.properties 
        //itemReader.setFetchSize(200);
        return itemReader;
    }


    @Bean(destroyMethod="")
    public FlatFileItemWriter<Employees> employeesWriter(){
        FlatFileItemWriter<Employees> fileItemWriter = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();
        //fileItemWriter.setResource(new FileSystemResource("csv/employees.csv"));
        fileItemWriter.setResource(new FileSystemResource("csv/employees-#{"+ formatter.format(new Date()) +"}.csv"));
        fileItemWriter.setHeaderCallback(headerCallback());

        BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<Employees> fieldExtractor = new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<>();
        fieldExtractor.setNames(new String[] {"employeeNumber", "lastName", "firstName", "extension", "email", "officeCode", "reportsTo", "jobTitle"});

        DelimitedLineAggregator<Employees> lineAggregator = new DelimitedLineAggregator<>();
        lineAggregator.setDelimiter(",");
        lineAggregator.setFieldExtractor(fieldExtractor);

        fileItemWriter.setLineAggregator(lineAggregator);
        fileItemWriter.setShouldDeleteIfEmpty(true);

        return fileItemWriter;
    } 

    // Step Execution
    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<Employees, Employees>chunk(10)
                .reader(employeesReader())
                .processor(employeesProcessor())
                .writer(employeesWriter())
                .build();
    }

    // Job Execution
    @Bean
    public Job exportemployeesJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory
                .get("employeesJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .flow(step1())
                .end()
                .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is about `com.prateek.scheduler.EmployeesRunScheduler`. Can you share the code of this class? According to the error, it has a field of type `Job` which is autowired and Spring does not know which job to inject in this field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I run only 2nd batch for my development and unit testing ?

You can use a profile for your second job and activate this profile only in development and unit testing

> How can I run all the batch jobs in one go ?

By default, Spring Boot executes all Jobs in the application context on startup in sequence (more details here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-batch-applications.html). If by "in one go" you mean starting all the jobs in parallel, you can use a `JobLauncher` backed by an asynchronous `TaskExecutor` (the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` for instance). More details here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/job.html#configuringJobLauncher

Comment: Thanks ! How we can skip particular batch ? Assume one batch job giving some performance issues etc, how to skip during the application context on startup of boot ? I feel we should be able to do, but did not find in documentation? Could you please show code how to use @Profile is batch job ?

Comment: Also, could you guide on the stack trace too ?

Comment: you can specify the jobs you want to run in the `spring.batch.job.names` property. For the profiles, please check the Spring Framework documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-definition-profiles